# Is there an adverb in here?

Tags: adverbs

Is there any adverb in the below sentences?

[Here in this link](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/tenses/simple_future.htm), it says **other adverbs can be used in similar constructions with various effects**.

> He is liable to get in trouble.
>   She is certain to do well in college.

But I don't know what word/phrase is the adverb here. I can identify "liable" & "certain" as adjectives - but can't guess which one is adverb that web page was referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't find the phrase "**other** adverbs" to be accurate because, as OP says, "liable" and "certain" are adjectives.

What the author may have meant to say is that similar sentences can be obtained by using adverbs, for example:

- He is liable to get in trouble.
- He will **probably** get in trouble.
- She is certain to do well in college.
- She will **certainly** do well in college.

Comment: How about **well**?

Comment: @RonaldSole Yes, of course "well" is an adverb, but if you read the site quoted by OP the underlined phrases for which adverbs are encouraged to be found are *is liable to get* and *is certain to do*.

Comment: I bow to your resourcefulness.